Creating a deep learning environment: an unsolvable error when downloading the scikit-misc package
Collecting scikit-misc
Using cached scikit_misc-0.2.0.tar.gz (247 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [17 lines of output]
+ meson setup /private/var/folders/fz/_9vjnd3108ldp9pp9l66swgr0000gn/T/pip-install-wnjt0p1c/scikit-misc_8b58ae08c95243f1b478e2d54d678191 /private/var/folders/fz/_9vjnd3108ldp9pp9l66swgr0000gn/T/pip-install-wnjt0p1c/scikit-misc_8b58ae08c95243f1b478e2d54d678191/.mesonpy-e6ut0255 -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=/private/var/folders/fz/_9vjnd3108ldp9pp9l66swgr0000gn/T/pip-install-wnjt0p1c/scikit-misc_8b58ae08c95243f1b478e2d54d678191/.mesonpy-e6ut0255/meson-python-native-file.ini
The Meson build system
Version: 1.6.0
Source dir: /private/var/folders/fz/_9vjnd3108ldp9pp9l66swgr0000gn/T/pip-install-wnjt0p1c/scikit-misc_8b58ae08c95243f1b478e2d54d678191
Build dir: /private/var/folders/fz/_9vjnd3108ldp9pp9l66swgr0000gn/T/pip-install-wnjt0p1c/scikit-misc_8b58ae08c95243f1b478e2d54d678191/.mesonpy-e6ut0255
Build type: native build
Project name: scikit-misc
Project version: 0.2.0
C compiler for the host machine: arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang (clang 14.0.6 "clang version 14.0.6")
C linker for the host machine: arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang ld64 530
Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 3.0.11)
Host machine cpu family: aarch64
Host machine cpu: aarch64
  ../meson.build:18:0: ERROR: Compiler /Users/wuyang/anaconda3/envs/py38tor19/bin/arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-gfortran cannot compile programs.
  
  A full log can be found at /private/var/folders/fz/_9vjnd3108ldp9pp9l66swgr0000gn/T/pip-install-wnjt0p1c/scikit-misc_8b58ae08c95243f1b478e2d54d678191/.mesonpy-e6ut0255/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
python downloads the scikit-misc package and reports an error.

You mention "unsolvable" in the title but the error log you posted doesn't say "unsolvable" anywhere, so how do you arrive at that conclusion? Could you please clarify is your problem is unsolvable or not? It will save time, since there's no point in looking for a solution that by definition cannot exist.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
